# View Downloaded PDF on UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uiwebview, alamofire

I have managed to download pdf file to the device.

I get this `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DBC9AFAB-3FD4-4D06-82F5-0577251001A7/Library/Caches/RewardMe-Presentation-at-NVIDIA-Auditorium.pdf` path

So I tried to open it on an UIWebView like this

```
    let downloadedFilePath = "file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DBC9AFAB-3FD4-4D06-82F5-0577251001A7/Library/Caches/RewardMe-Presentation-at-NVIDIA-Auditorium.pdf"
    let filePathURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: downloadedFilePath);
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url));
```

But the WebView fails to load the pdf. It only shows a blank webview

Any ideas why this does not work?

Comment: make use of NSFileManager to get path and set it to UIWebView , it should work

Comment: The path i get after downloaded the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code looks ok but the path is not

```
 let downloadedFilePath = "///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DBC9AFAB-3FD4-4D06-82F5-0577251001A7/Library/Caches/RewardMe-Presentation-at-NVIDIA-Auditorium.pdf"
        let filePathURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: downloadedFilePath);
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url));
```

Try this hope it works.

For checking that the file exist  **Open a new finder and press Command+Shift+G** after that copy and paste the file path and press enter
If the file load then the file exist. File path in your case is  "  **///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/DBC9AFAB-3FD4-4D06-82F5-0577251001A7/Library/Caches/RewardMe-Presentation-at-NVIDIA-Auditorium.pdf** "

Comment: I am running this on my iPhone. Thanks for helping